# Unable to click button within a span using javascript or xpath

Tags: javascript, xpath, robotframework

I am using RobotFramework (RF) to test a web app. I want to click a button within a popout. I have tried xpath and javascript to find the element. SeleniumLibrary says that that element has been clicked, but on the frontend UI side, I can't see that the button is actually clicked because the event is expected to display selection of items. What the script result says is not sync to what shows in the UI. Manual click works fine.

Here are the js and xpath codes I tried...

```
Execute Javascript 
 document.querySelector("#CallOutcomes_InboundInbound_menuPlace").querySelector('.hierarchicalMenuButton').click()

Execute Javascript 
   document.querySelector("#CallOutcomes_InboundInbound_menuPlace").querySelectorAll('span[style="height: 0px;"]')[0].querySelector("#startMenuButton").click()

Execute Javascript 
   document.querySelector("#CallOutcomes_InboundInbound_menuPlace").querySelectorAll('span[style="height: 0px;"]')[0].querySelector('.hierarchicalMenuButton').click()

Click Element   //*[@id="CallOutcomes_InboundInbound_menuPlace"]//*[contains(@class,"hierarchicalMenuButton")]
```

Here is the html snippet...

```html
<pre class="showQueryMenuTable" id="CallOutcomes_InboundInbound_menuPlace">
<span style="height: 0px;">
<input type="button" class="hierarchicalMenuButton" value="Call Outcomes" id="startMenuButton">
```

When I try the javascript code in the console, the locator is able to find the element but when .click() is added, that's when things go array: the button is not being clicked.

Is there anything special I need to do here? It works fine with other buttons/elements. What am I missing?

See image here: 
[image: Robot test result says passed but in reality not]

----- Edited 10 Jan 2020 ----

I've discovered that the event for the button is a mouse down, not click. Surprisingly, the RF's Mouse Down keyword does not work. So I figured I'd used Javascript's instead.

```
Execute javascript    document.querySelector("#CallOutcomes_InboundInbound_menuPlace .hierarchicalMenuButton").dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousedown',{}));
```

That command fixed it. I am not sure what the long term effect of this to my script but it works in the interim. Cheers!

Comment: I guess your script will be clicking the element the right button. Can you get the x&y values of the element rather clicking and see if the x&y>0.

Comment: Apparently, the event is a mousedown. I'll have to figure out how that works. Thanks @supputuri

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with this new discovery, so that others who may land upon this question will see it in the right context. In addition, have you had a look a the SeleniumLibrary keywords for [Mouse Down](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Mouse%20Down)?

Comment: Hi @A.Kootstra, I am still working on the solution. Surprisingly, the SeleniumLibrary Mouse Down keyword does not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that the event for the button is a mouse down, not click. Surprisingly, the RF's Mouse Down keyword does not work. So I figured I'd used Javascript's instead.

```
Execute javascript    document.querySelector("#CallOutcomes_InboundInbound_menuPlace .hierarchicalMenuButton").dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousedown',{}));
```

That command fixed it. I am not sure what the long term effect of this to my script but it works in the interim. Cheers!